# how to add images to text adventure, and html

Tags: javascript, html

ok so basically I'm doing an assignment for school and its a text based adventure game and i was wondering how to add text to a page after you pick a choice this is my work in javascript thus far:

```js
var BookMark = 0;
var StoryHere = 0;
var Choice1Here = 0;
var Choice2Here = 0;

function StartStory() {
  StoryHere = document.getElementById('Story');
  Choice1Here = document.getElementById('Choice1');
  Choice2Here = document.getElementById('Choice2');

  postPage();

  return;
}

function Choice1() {
  console.log('Choice 1 clicked ->' + BookMark);
  BookMark = Page[BookMark + 1] * 3;

  clearPage();
  setTimeout(postPage, 1000);

  return;
}

function Choice2() {
  console.log('Choice 2 clicked ->' + BookMark);
  BookMark = Page[BookMark + 2] * 3;
  clearPage();
  setTimeout(postPage, 1000);
  return;
}

function postPage() {
  StoryHere.innerHTML = MyStory[BookMark];
  Choice1Here.innerHTML = MyStory[BookMark + 1];
  Choice2Here.innerHTML = MyStory[BookMark + 2];
}

function clearPage() {
  StoryHere.innerHTML = '';
  Choice1Here.innerHTML = '';
  Choice2Here.innerHTML = '';
}
```

and this is on my second javascript page which is linked with the original through HTML so i can put it on a web page

```js
var MyStory = ['test', 'test', 'test'];

const Page = [0, 0, 0];
```

some help would be much apricated I thought maybe I could do it some way with CSS but again I wouldn't know how to go about doing that
also heres my html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>story time</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
<script src="story_book.js"></script>
<script src="story_main.js"></script>

</head>
<body onload="StartStory();">
<div id="Story">

</div>
<div id="Choice1" onclick="Choice1();">


</div>
<div id="Choice2" onclick="Choice2();">


</div> 
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

you did not post your HTML, but basically easiest way how to add an image by JS is to:
add it to your html and hide it with CSS

```
<div id="image" style="display:none">
  <img src="YOUR_IMAGE" width="200px" height="200px" />
</div>
```

and show it when needed with JS

```
document.getElementById('image').style.display = "contents";
```